# Why colors are not displaying in VIM - OH-MY-ZSH

Tags: vim, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have seen this post :

[oh-my-zsh themes don't show properly (background stays white)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056007/oh-my-zsh-themes-dont-show-properly-background-stays-white)

But nothing helped.

Problem is in MAC VIM Colors are displaying messed but in linux all colors are working fine.

I am using iTerm 2 as in tutorial but here's how colors are showing.

[image]

Why this is not working ?

I think it should be link this :

[image]

Here are my settings in iTerm2

[image]

Comment: tutorial?  Which vim colorscheme are you using?

Comment: Maybe you need `set t_Co=256` if you use a 256 colors scheme but your terminal doesn't tell vim it supports 256 colors.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Test to see whether syntax highlighting is enabled in Vim. If you type `:syntax on` and the problem goes away then that's your issue, and you can correct it by adding:

```
syntax on
```

to your `$MYVIMRC` file (usually at `~/.vimrc` or `~/.vim/vimrc`.
Find out exactly with `:echo $MYVIMRC` in Vim).

In case no such file exists then create a file `~/.vimrc` and add `syntax on` to it and save the file.

Comment: If I type `:syntax on` it works. But I have no variable `$MYVIMRC` for a permanent fix.

Comment: How to permanently have `:syntax on` ? Do I have to type it every time?

Comment: Just create a file ~/.vimrc and `syntax on` to it and save. It worked for me even though I didn't have any variable $MYVIMRC

Comment: Thanks, syntax on is definitely NOT enabled. Adding that in the ~/.vimrc file solved it.